# Convert System.Linq.IQueryable to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I'm new to asp.net mvc & I'm trying to make a website with asp.net mvc 4 & EF6 where user can sort a table after login. I'm getting a compile error saying `Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`. My codes are below,

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Login(string sortOrder)
    {
        if (Session["UserNAME"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.CodeSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "code_desc" : "";
            var sortedOut = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.AsQueryable() };     //Error in this line

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "code_desc":
                    sortedOut = sortedOut.OrderByDescending(s => s.MKISTAT_CODE);
                    break;
                default:
                    sortedOut = sortedOut.OrderBy(s => s.MKISTAT_CODE);
                    break;
            }
            return View(sortedOut.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class MkistatVsUserLogin
{
    public mkistat mkistats { get; set; }
    public idx Idxs { get; set; }
}
```

How can I solve this problem. Need this help badly. Tnx.

UPDATES

**Mkistat Model**

```
public partial class mkistat
{
    public string MKISTAT_CODE { get; set; }
    public int MKISTAT_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string MKISTAT_QUOTE_BASES { get; set; }
    public decimal MKISTAT_OPEN_PRICE { get; set; }
    public decimal MKISTAT_HIGH_PRICE { get; set; }
    public decimal MKISTAT_LOW_PRICE { get; set; }
    public decimal MKISTAT_SPOT_TOTAL_VALUE { get; set; }
    public string MKISTAT_LM_DATE_TIME { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: what's the definition of ``mkistat``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your model and set `mkistats` type to `IQueryable<mkistat>` , you are passing `IQueryable<mkistat>` where your property is of Type `mkistat` not `IQueryable<mkistat>`, you have to do  like this:

```
public class MkistatVsUserLogin
{
    public IQueryable<mkistat> mkistats { get; set; }
    public idx Idxs { get; set; }
}
```

and now in your action:

```
var sortedOut = new MkistatVsUserLogin 
                   { 
                     mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.AsQueryable(); 
                   };
```

If you want to do with `List<mkistat>` htne your model should be like:

```
public class MkistatVsUserLogin
{
    public List<mkistat> mkistats { get; set; }
    public idx Idxs { get; set; }
}
```

and in action:

```
var sortedOut = new MkistatVsUserLogin 
                   { 
                     mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.ToList(); 
                   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently mkistats are implementing I generic collection, and by calling .AsQueryable() you are making an iQueryable collection. If you need it to be queryable, change mkistats to implement iQueryable.

Otherwise you can call .toList() on it, but you lose queryable support and lazy loading, if those are important.

Edit: It looks like you don't need queryable, so just do this:

```
var sortedOut = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = dsedb.mkistats.AsQueryable().toList() };
```

Likely you could also just leave both the .AsQueryable() and the .toList(). But it doesn't really matter and I can't decipher how your code fits together.

Comment: TnQ. Can u give me the explanation by code? It'll be really helpful.

Comment: Getting error. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyMvcProj.Models.mkistat>' to 'MyMvcProj.Models.mkistat'`